# Mocha test async function which not explicit return a promise

Tags: asynchronous, mocha.js

Target function :

```
function resolveSteup(resolve, oInitialCreationPromise) {
oInitialCreationPromise ? oInitialCreationPromise.then(() => {
    console.log(
        `create successfully`
    );
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error(
        `Failed to create due to : ${error.message}`
    );
}).finally(resolve) : resolve();
```

}

The resolveSteup function do not return a promise explicitly, how to test with mocha? We don't want return a promise with production code. how to make below test case. Any best practice for this case? Thanks very much!

```
it('Should resolve finally even initial create project promise rejected', function () {
        let fnResolveStub = sinon.stub();
        resolveSteup(fnResolveStub, Promise.reject());
        expect(fnResolveStub.calledOnce).to.be.true;
```

});